# How to get name of exe which is trying to access internet?

Tags: delphi, winapi, network-programming, firewall, delphi-2009

I'm developing an application that is able to determine which application using internet. Now my problem is that i want to know the process name before it successfully establish connection much like a firewall.

I'm using Delphi2009. So the suggestions in that technology are appreciated.

Comment: How are you hooking the connections to begin with?  It makes a difference in how you access the socket IP/Port information. Once you have that, you have look up the process ID in the OS's network tables, and then from that you can open the process and query its filename.

Comment: Once you know the name of the EXE trying to access the network, what will you do?

Comment: @selbie-- After that I've two option either block or allow it to access network.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That may useful. actually i want to monitor application instantly when it gonna to make connection. is any API available for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Winsock Layered Service Providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) to monitor traffic. I believe LSPs are DLLs that get loaded into each process, so you should be able to call [GetModuleFileName(NULL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to discover the EXE name when your DLL is loaded.

The Wikipedia article linked above shares my strongest concerns:

> One major common issue with LSPs was that if they were to be removed
>   or unregistered improperly or if the LSP was buggy, it would result in
>   corruption of the Winsock catalog in the registry, and the entire
>   TCP/IP stack would break and the computer could no longer access the
>   network.

So if you are new to Windows programming and/or do not take proper precautions with writing these types of filter drives, then tread carefully.  Otherwise, a bug in your program will easily screw up the user's machine.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the precaution.

Comment: Any Snippet of Code will be appreciated.